# Indentation in Google form + error

Tags: python, request, python-requests, urllib2, indentation

I'm creating a script to submit multiple answers to a Google Form. I can't set the right indentation in draftResponse. This form sets an unique fbzx value everytime you go on the page, which I'm scraping with bs4.

I should post this draftResponse [null,null,"fbzx value"], but I can't indent it, heres my payload + fbzx scraping

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import random
from random import getrandbits
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def ping():

  url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/viewform'

  page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
  fbzx = soup.findAll('input', {"type": "hidden", "name": "fbzx"})

  email = 'test{}@domain.com'.format(getrandbits(40))
  Sizelist = ['8','9','10','11','12']
  size = random.choice(Sizelist)
  nome = "test"
  cognome = "test"
  anno = "12"
  mese = "12"
  giorno = "12"
  via = "ciao"
  cap = "22000"
  citta = "city"
  nazione = "italy"
  telefono = ""
  instagram = "asdlol"
  sentinel = ""
  termini = "Autorizzo il trattamento dei miei dati personali, ai sensi del D.lgs. 196 del 30 giugno 2003"
  fvventer code here = "1"
  draftResponse = ???
  pageHistory = "0"
  fbzx = fbzx

s = "https://docs.google.com/formResponse?emailAddress="+email+"+&entry.1884265043="+nome+"&entry.1938400468="+cognome+"&entry.1450673532_year="+anno+"&entry.1450673532_month="+mese+"&entry.1450673532_day="+giorno+"&entry.71493440="+via+"&entry.1981412943="+cap+"&entry.950259558="+citta+"&entry.1622497152="+nazione+"&entry.1850033056="+telefono+"&entry.769447175="+instagram+"&entry.256744251_sentinel="+sentinel+"&entry.256744251="+termini+"&entry715796591="+size+"&fvv="+fvv+"&draftResponse="+draftResponse+"&pageHistory="+pageHistory+"&fbzx="+fbzx

getSite = requests.get(s)
if getSite.status_code == 200:
    return True
def loop(N):
for x in range(1, N+1):
    if ping():
        print ('{} / {} inseriti'.format(x,N))

loop(2000)
```

Hope it's clear and I'm open to your suggestions and corrections of course